# remove a subgroup owner from gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I am the owner of a gitlab group that has many subgroups. This main group had 3 owners, I removed one owner from the group but he is still owner in the subgroups of the group.

Question: How do I remove him from beeing owner in subgroups

[Group owners img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ7NH.png)

[Subgroup owners img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVGF7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't currently a great way to do this, but it's a known issue that should be fixed in version 11.10 (April 22 2019). There is a workaround suggested here though: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/38564#workaround-added-11-27-by-asaba-referenced-from-discussion-below

> 1. Explicitly add another user as the owner of the subgroup.
> 2. Controls should reappear, allowing other owners to be removed.